# How to derive the following estimation in PDE?

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I am reading Qing Han & Fanghua Lin’s book *Elliptic partial differential equations*. In the section 2.4 Gradient estimate, I come across a trouble understanding the following  step:
[image]

Here is some of my manuscript:

use the ellipticity assumption we can get 
    $$\textcircled{1}\geqslant 2\lambda |D^{2}u|^{2}$$
And $\textcircled{4}$ is easily:
    $$\textcircled{4}\geqslant -|Du|^{2}-|Df|^{2}$$
    For $\textcircled{2}$, I estimate it as follows: since
    $$|2D_{k}a_{ij}D_{ij}uD_{k}u|\leq \frac{1}{2}[2(D_{k}a_{ij})^{2}+2(D_{ij}u)^{2}(D_{k}u)^{2} ]=(D_{k}a_{ij})^{2}+(D_{ij}u)^{2}(D_{k}u)^{2} $$
    So 
    $$\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k}2D_{k}a_{ij}D_{ij}uD_{k}u\leq\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k}  (D_{k}a_{ij})^{2} +\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k} (D_{ij}u)^{2}(D_{k}u)^{2} =\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k}  (D_{k}a_{ij})^{2} +|D^{2}u|^{2}|Du|^{2}$$
    Thus we get 
    $$\textcircled{2}\geq-\sum_{i}\sum_{j}\sum_{k}  (D_{k}a_{ij})^{2} -|D^{2}u|^{2}|Du|^{2} $$
    Similarly I get estimation for $\textcircled{3}$
    $$\textcircled{3}\geq -\sum_{i}\sum_{k}(D_{k}b_{i})^{2}-|Du|^{2}|Du|^{2}=-\sum_{i}\sum_{k}(D_{k}b_{i})^{2}-|Du|^{4}$$

I am not sure whether I am on the right way.  My confusion is: I will get a $|Du|^{4}$ term which vanished on the book. Can anyone help me figure out that estimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you have $L^{\infty}$ control on the coefficients $a_{ij}, b_j$ and its first derivatives, so you can ignore them. Then each term is essentially quadratic (or of lower order) in $Du$ and $D^2u,$ which you can split appropriately using Young's inequality.

More precisely if we let $K$ be the sum of $C^1(\overline\Omega)$ norms of $a_{ij}, b_j$ and $f,$ then we can estimate

\begin{align}
2a_{ij}D_{ki}uD_{kj}u &\geq 2\lambda |D^2u|^2, \\
-2D_ka_{ij}D_kuD_{ij}u &\geq -2K |Du||D^2u| \geq -\lambda|D^2u|^2 - \frac{K^2}{\lambda}|Du|,\\
-2D_kb_iD_kuD_iu &\geq - 2K|Du|^2, \\
2D_zf|Du|^2 &\geq -K^2 - |Du|^2, \\
2D_kfD_ku &\geq - K^2 - |Du|^2.
\end{align}
Hence putting it all together,
$$ L(|Du|^2) \geq \lambda |D^2u|^2 - \left( \frac{K^2}{\lambda} + 2K + K\right)|Du|^2 - 2K^2.$$